# Rejection of suggested edit that fixes multiple issues

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I suggested [this edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1105295) that was rejected with the reason it didn't improve the quality of the post.

The suggested edit improved 3 problems with the post following consensus about editing guidelines:

1. [Removed tagged keyword from title.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)
2. [Corrected casing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303220) of tech names.
3. [Removed salutations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Each of the above is considered enough reason to edit a post, but on Super User correcting multiple issues with a post still leads to suggested edits being rejected.

Can someone explain why edit reviewing criteria on Super User doesn't follow the established guidelines of the network?

Comment: That should not have been rejected. I've approved it for you. Thanks for bring this to our attention.

Comment: @DavidPostill thank you for your attention on this.